# Send Messages from Azure to Mobile phone number

Tags: azure, mobile, messaging, mobile-phones

I need to send messages(Not Push Notifications) using Microsoft Azure. I have an account and can you guide to me for any documentation.

Scenario: I Need to send messages to a mobile no using Azure. How can I do this?

Do I need to do an AJAX call using JS? Or Can I achieve it any programming language?
Please guide me.

Thank You,
Srikar Nagadevara

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at these links, they are doing what you are describing.

Send SMS: https://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/send-text-messages-sms-from-web-api-using-azure-mobile-services/

http://www.sms-integration.com/sms-from-azure-227.html